# Proving partial orders in set theory for $(x_1,y_1 )≤(x_2,y_2 )⇔〖(x〗_1 ≤_X x_2$ and $x_2 ≰_X x_1)$ or $(x_1 =_X x_2$ and $y_1 ≤_Y y_2)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

I'm trying to prove partial order for a set, but I can't seem to be able to fully understand what I'm doing and weather I'm doing it right at all. I don't think I understand how to work with all the conditions between the two partial oders when proving antisymmetry and transitivity because of all the conditions I have to work with to get there.

The exercise is as follows:
 Let X be a partial order with the sign $$≤_X$$ and Y be a partial order with the sign $$≤_Y$$  Prove that the following is a partial order for $$X\times Y$$ given that: $$(x_1,y_1 ) \le (x_2,y_2 ) \iff (x_1 \le_X x_2 \text{ and } x_2 \not \le_X x_1)\text{  or  }(x_1 =_X x_2 \text { and } y_1 \le_Y y_2)$$

Comment: Check the definition in the last formula again, please! At the end of the first parenthesis, $x_1 \not \le_X x_1$ is always false, and at the beginning of the second parenthesis $x_1 =_X x_2$ makes not much sense, as $X$ defines an order, not an equality.

Comment: I corrected the mistake with the x1≰Xx1, it is suppose to be x2≰Xx1. And with the x1=Xx2 I think the meaning is that since X is a partial order in itself then $$ X_1 <_x X_2$$ and $$ X_2 >_x X_1$$.

Comment: A partial order is antisymmetric, that means $a \le b$ and $b \le a$ implies $a=b$. $x_1=x_2$ makes sense, $x_1$ and $x_2$ are just the same. What I'm meaning with $x_1 =_X x_2$ making no sense is that there is no additional information or structure provided with it, it just the same as $x_1=x_2$,for any $X$.
Now the problems makes sense (to me). Try to understand what the first parenthesis wants to express, maybe you can express that in a simpler formula as first step to understanding what it *means*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I preassume that $=_X$ denotes the equality relation on $X$.

Then relation $\leq$ on $X\times Y$ is defined by:$$(x_1,y_1)\leq(x_2,y_2)\iff [x_1<_X x_2\text{ or }(x_1=x_2\text{ and }y_1\leq_Y y_2)]$$where $x_1<_X x_2$ abbreviates $x_1\leq_X x_2\text{ and }x_1\neq x_2$.

Based on $x_1=x_1\text{ and }y_1=y_1$ we then find that $(x_1,y_1)\leq(x_1,y_1)$, proving reflexivity.

In order to prove transitivity let $(x_1,y_1)\leq(x_2,y_2)$ and $(x_2,y_2)\leq(x_3,y_3)$.

Now discern the following cases:

- $x_1<_X x_2$ and $x_2<_Xx_3$ leading to $x_1<_X x_3$
- $x_1<_X x_2$ and $[x_2=x_3\text{ and }y_2\leq_Y y_3]$ leading to $x_1<_X x_3$
- $[x_1=x_2\text{ and }y_1\leq_Y y_2]$ and $x_2<_X x_3$ leading to $x_1<_X x_3$
- $[x_1=x_2\text{ and }y_1\leq_Y y_2]$ and $[x_2=x_3\text{ and }y_2\leq_Y y_3]$ leading to $[x_1=x_3\text{ and }y_1\leq_Y y_3]$

In each case the conclusion $(x_1,y_1)\leq(x_3,y_3)$ is justified, so this proves transitivity.

Now it remains to prove antisymmetry, and for that let  $(x_1,y_1)\leq(x_2,y_2)$ and $(x_2,y_2)\leq(x_1,y_1)$.

On base of this it must be shown that $(x_1,y_1)=(x_3,y_3)$.

As above discern $4$ cases and give it a try yourself.

Let me know if you run into troubles.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had a look at it again and tried to solve it myslef. I managed to get nearly all the way to proving transitivity but I have a problem with combining all the cases you've stated back to the original condition for $$(x_1,y_1)≤(x_3,y_3)$$. I can see the $$x_1 = x_3 and y_1 ≤_Y y_3$$ part but I can't figure out how to reach the first condition being $$(x_1 ≤_X x_2 and x_2 ≰_X x_1)$$ I assume that between all the bullets for proving transitivity ther'e 'or's.

Comment: I had a look at it again and I think I got it. I worked with all the conditions together and ended up having 4 different conditions with 'or's between them and 2 of them were $$x_1=x_3 and y_1 ≤_Y y_3$$ and the second: $$x_1 ≤_X x_3 and x_3≰X x_1$$ So basically I have a the conditions I need to prove that $$(x_1,y_1) <= (x_3,y_3)$$

Comment: and in my first comment I meant $$x_3$$ insted of $$x_2$$

Comment: To get more clarity I ask you the following questions: 1) do you understand that $x_1\leq_X x_2\text{ and }\neg[x_2\leq_X x_1]$ is exactly the same as the more handsome $x_1<_X x_2$?  2) do you agree with the proof in my answer of transitivity? 3) have you managed to prove antisymmetry, or are you still wrestling with that?

Comment: doesn't the ≤ sign only denote the partial order and not the regular ≤ sign, so there can't be only a '<' sign? and can't ¬x1 be equall to either x2 or x3? (since it's the complement).

Comment: *Every* partial order $\leq$  induces a strict partial order $<$. This by stating that $x<y\iff x\leq y\text{ and }x\neq y$. Further $\neg[x_2\leq_X x_1]$ is just another notation for $x_{2}\nleq_{X}x_{1}$ and has nothing to do with complements.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot!

Comment: and by the way, out of curiosity, how would you prove the antisymmetry? I got to 4 cases as we had above when 3 of them were false (because for example x1 cant be greater than x2 and vice versa at the same time) and the last statement was $$x_1=x_2 and y_1=y_2$$, hence => $$(x_1,y_1)=(x_2,y_2)$$